# Never Completed Game

Tags: riddle, cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, unsolved-mysteries

> The seventeenth of the primes.
> Its twin is twentynine.
> Po.
> Let’s drive.
> Bye, Alfonsín.
> Add seven triangular.
> Sweet.
> It named the Valley.

[image: never completed game]

This riddle is taken from https://www.nevercompletedgame.com/
It is the final question of the challenge (number 41), and it has not been solved yet. My guess so far is that each line refers to a two-digit number, and that the numbers form some kind of a cipher, since my guesses contain some repeated numbers. My guesses for the numbers on each line:

1. 59 (the seventeenth prime number)
2. 31 (29's twin prime)
3. 84 (atomic number of Polonium)
4. 16 (first word in the song "Let's Drive" by John Oates)
5. 89 (year that Raúl Alfonsín left office)
6. 84 (sum of the first seven triangular numbers)
7. 16 (sweet sixteen)
8. 14 (atomic number of Silicon)

I have tried using a number to letter online decoder and a base 26 decoder, but I wasn't able to get anything meaningful with these numbers. I'm not 100% positive on any of them really, I might be completely off with my entire approach. The answers and explanations for the first 40 on this website are given here, for those that want to skip to 41 and test their solutions for this riddle:

https://pastebin.com/dSZV9eUq

Comment: Isn't this like an ongoing competition? I know that it's not really a competition, but I'm not sure that the creators of the game would be happy if the knew the question has been solved by a puzzling community.

Comment: The first 40 questions were solved by a community. This question was made precisely to stump an entire community working on it. It remains unsolved for nearly 2 years, so I don't think the creator would be upset if the solution were finally uncovered, if there even is one at all.

Comment: I am not certain, but I was also wondering if the shape of the text could possibly have any significance. I have written it out to look exactly how it was displayed on the website. I have also tried interpreting the numbers as geographic coordinates or IP addresses, but that did not seem to lead anywhere.

Comment: What happens when you arrange the lines by length? (just a thought, might be wrong. )

Comment: Interesting idea. It makes kind of a traffic cone shape that way, not a pyramid like I had expected. I tried putting the numbers into the ciphers using the new order, but did not get anything that looks meaningful.

Comment: I noticed something peculiar when using an alternative set of numbers. Initially, I had 82 for line 5 (age at which Alfonsin died) and 28 for line 6 (the seventh triangular number). I don't think these choices fit the clues quite as well as 89 and 84, but when using this alternative set, I noticed that adding pairs of consecutive numbers produces a list of nice, round numbers: 90, 100, 110, and 30. I tried interpreting this set as an IP address, and a quick geolocation look up told me that it is located in Sens, France. But, from there, I was not able to make any further progress.

Comment: Again, this entire approach could be completely misguided, the clues might just be related to each other in a different way, apart from referencing numbers. Please post any sort of hunch or strategy that comes to mind. This riddle requires a team effort to be solved.

Comment: Bye, Alfonsín  - maybe the number from his last date when he deid.

Comment: There has to be a reason **twentynine** is written as one word.

Comment: In case this helps - Twentynine Palms, CA - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twentynine_Palms,_California

Comment: And could this be a coincidence?? There are 17 projects in CA's Public Hospital Redesign and Incentives in Medi-Cal (PRIME) program https://caph.org/priorities/medi-cal-2020-waiver/prime/prime-projects/

Answer (score 2):

after  too much time on this, that is what I found:

> [This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/firstworldanarchists/comments/73kfmm/never_completed_game/) said the numbers might be 59 31 14 3 89 84 16 14 that the coordinates

> for
>  59 31 14 3 =  [Novgorodsky District, Novgorod Oblast, Russia](https://www.google.com/maps/place/59%C2%B000%2700.0%22N+31%C2%B014%2703.0%22E/@58.5852186,31.3907691,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d59!4d31.2341667)
>  89 84 16 14 = [Arctic Ocean](https://www.google.com/maps/place/89%C2%B000%2700.0%22N+84%C2%B016%2714.0%22E/@84.9995619,84.2705556,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d89!4d84.2705556)

> these places are 2,745 miles or 4,417 km apart
>  As you can see on the [wikipedia page of Novgorodsky District](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novgorodsky_District) is have a connection to the Arctic Ocean

But maybe I am just overthinking...

Answer (score -3):

I might be wrong but I think the answer is:

> either the valley of tribulation or the valley of seven triangles. I mostly believe in the latter. Too bad you can't find out if it's right. The guy who made the game is from Sweden and I haven't been able to contact him

Comment: Please explain why you think that. Also, please use proper English.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Please ensure your answers include an explanation for your final answer. If you are interested in learning more about this site (and earning another badge) check out the Help Center: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help